# Is this neither a tautology or contradiction?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-verification

I'm writing to verify my conclusion the following is neither a tautology nor contradiction:

[image]

This can be rearranged into the form:

$$(q \land(p\lor r)) \lor\lnot q$$

All it takes from here is to consider the case where both P and R are false, as well as Q being True; then the overall expression is false. All other cases this expression is true however.

Am I correct on this?

Comment: A tautology is a proposition that is true regardless of the truth values of the variables. A contradiction is a proposition that is false regardless of the truth values of the variables. So you are correct that this proposition is neither.

Comment: Yes, you are correct!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right.

It's not a contradiction because if $p, q, r$ are true, the statement is true; it's not a tautology because if $q$ is true and $p, r$ are false, the statement is false.